Can`t get constraint.HasConstraints working in Lua gmod
I`m writing a gmod lua script which checks if there are constraints for prop spawned by user (like ropes), but it always return false even if I spawn constrained props
if SERVER then
    hook.Add("PlayerSpawnedProp", "PrintConstraintsCount", function(player, entity)
        print(constraint.HasConstraints(entity))
    end)
end


You should expand your print test, to show other values, make sure what you are seeing the false printing for is the rope you expect it to be checking. add things specifically from the entity that you pass in to HasConstraints
